# LWJGL 3 - Rendering Text

Tags: java, opengl, text, lwjgl

I'm trying to render text in LWJGL 3 using non-deprecated OpenGL. I cannot use Slick-Util, which relies on older versions of LWJGL and deprecated OpenGL.

I would use FreeType if I was writing in standard C++ OpenGL, but I cannot. So how would I begin to create a class that can handle text rendering, with support for:

- Different fonts / font sizes / bold, italics, etc
- Font coloring
- Font transforms

Does anyone have any good resources on this subject, preferably in Java and LWJGL?

Comment: You would take an AWT Font as input, then draw every letter from 0 to 256 on a BufferedImage using the Graphics object. The font size/color is not changeable at runtime with this approach, but it is widely used.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Could you provide an example of what you're talking about, please? Just so I understand what to do. @JackWhiteIII

Comment: [this](https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.java) is Slick2D's way of doing it. They use immediate mode, but I'm sure you'd be able to convert it to non-deprecated code.

Comment: Reading your question again, my comment doesn't seem to make so much sense. What i really wanted to say is that Slick2D is pretty much using the best approach there is when it comes to actually creating the font, but to render the font, you'd need to convert their `drawQuad` method to newest OpenGL standards. I am not familiar with the new standards, they seem unnecessarily complicated to me, but basically you just need a VBO and somehow populate the array values (which really is what gets me every time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWJGL3 has a built in binding to STB which can load TTF font files, there are examples in the LWJGL3 repo which show you how to render text using it.

Further details and examples for the same can be found [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-stb-bindings/36153/view.html).

Comment: Those examples all use deprecated OpenGL :/ @Gavin

Comment: Main thing you need to look at is the STB api's, they can easily be implemented using modern OpenGL.

Comment: i can't render text, any solution ?

Comment: Please provide an example here since the link provided is now invalid.